# RKRequestQueue (RestKit) How to ensure order of downloads

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm queueing a bunch of files and was wondering how to ensure that the download requests are performed in ORDER.

So far, when queueing requests, all requests are async and don't come back in order.

Any ideas on how to enforce this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you use the default RestKit network client, it uses the **RKRequestQueue** to organize the requests. This class has the property called **concurrentRequestsLimit**. Set it to one to enforce sequential mode:

```
[[[RKClient sharedClient] requestQueue] setConcurrentRequestsLimit:1];
```